# How to generate Excel file using HTML+CSS in C#

Tags: c#, html, excel

I have HTML file with internal styles. Using this HTML file, I need to create Excel file. I tried out below scenario. 
Get the HTML content to string using HTMLAgilityPack and save it as below.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HTML.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Output.Write(htmlContent);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Then Excel file is saved. But styles don't apply to it. That way take only inline styles. I'm using ASP.NET MVC. What is the best way to do this?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Some text </p>
<p>paragraph </p>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at EPPlus (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). This library supports the generation of Excel files (xlsx) without Office installed. So you don't have to rely on Excel catching the HTML from the browser and formatting it, but you can do it all by yourself and as per your requirements.

Comment: My requirement is create Excel file using HTML file. Is it can be done using EPPlus?

Comment: Maybe you can parse the HTML with HtmlAgilityPack and then create the Excel sheet with EPPlus then.